# Variables between bash and php-cli

Tags: php, bash, variables, export, environment-variables

I want to pass variables from bash to php in 1 script. I know it's possible with 2 files and $argv in the php, but I would really like to put the script in 1 file. This is what i got now:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is bash"
export VAR="blabla"

/usr/bin/php << EOF
<?php

echo getenv("VAR");

?>
EOF
```

which works fine. But there is one problem: i can't seem to store the getenv in a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is bash"
export VAR="blabla"

/usr/bin/php << EOF
<?php

$var = getenv("VAR");
echo $var;

?>
EOF
```

Gives me this error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in - on line 3

I get the same error if i even try to define a basic variable like $var = "hello";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prevent the shell from interpreting the PHP script, quote the delimiter for your here doc:

```
/usr/bin/php << 'EOF'
<?php $var = getenv("VAR"); echo $var; ?>
EOF
```

Comment: Yes, i think this is the easiest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that both bash and php use the dollar sign for variables. When you say this in your heredoc:

```
$var = getenv("VAR");
```

bash tried to replace `$var` with the value of the shell variable `var` and that's probably empty; the result is that PHP sees something like this:

```
<?php

= getenv("VAR");
echo ;

?>
```

Hence the "unexpected '='" error.

Try escaping the dollar signs in your PHP:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is bash"
export VAR="blabla"

/usr/bin/php << EOF
<?php

\$var = getenv("VAR");
echo \$var;

?>
EOF
```

A bash heredoc evaluates variables just like a double quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

You've ran into one pitfall that comes with the way you want to tackle things, which is put two scripts in one file, one for Bash, the other one for PHP. The problem is that the `$var` is interpreted by the shell, leaving PHP with `= getenv("VAR");` where a statement is expected, hence the syntax error.

Another thing is that you don't need to pull the VAR from the env as long as you keep both scripts in one file (which I think is a bad idea to start with).

Here's how you can to it (not tested):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is bash"
VAR="blabla" # normal variable, no need to export

/usr/bin/php << EOF
<?php
\$var = "$VAR"; # access variable
echo \$var;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Why simply not use `STDIN`:

`echo lala.txt |  php -r '$line = trim(fgets(STDIN))if(is_file($line)){echo "1";}else{echo "0";}'`